# ODBC Oracle driver in Windows Home Basic Premium

Tags: oracle10g, odbc, oracle11g

I am using the operating system Windows Home Basic Premium. I installed Oracle 10g Express Edition also 11g, it installed correctly but when I would go for adding driver from ODBC I didn't find any Express driver.

That's why I can't run any Java database project; it shows me driver not loaded. This is first I face problem using any software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in general, you should not be using ODBC if you are developing a Java application.  Java applications generally use the JDBC driver to connect to the database.  It is possible to use a JDBC to ODBC bridge driver but that was really only appropriate years ago when not every database had a JDBC driver.  There would be no reason to use a JDBC to ODBC bridge driver to connect to an Oracle database in an application built today.

That being said, are you using a 32-bit version of Windows or a 64-bit version of Windows?  Did you install 32-bit versions of Oracle or 64-bit versions of Oracle?  If you are using a 64-bit version of Windows, the default ODBC Driver Administrator will only display the 64-bit ODBC drivers that are installed.  If you installed 32-bit versions of Oracle, you'll need to open the 32-bit ODBC Driver Administrator at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe in order to access the 32-bit ODBC drivers.